# Querying on unique ID in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to Google App Engine and I'm trying to query on the unique identifier of the datastore. For example, I am trying to query on the `ID/Name` field of the image attached below.

[Image of Local Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L5lJ.png)

As of now, the code I have is of follows. `listID` is the ID as a `long` that I am passing into the `KeyFactory`. In this case it is `4573968371548160` or the first one in the picture.

```
Key listKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Lists", listID);
Query.FilterPredicate listFilter = new Query.FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, listKey);
Query listQuery = new Query("Lists").setFilter(listFilter);
List<Entity> listResults = datastore.prepare(listQuery).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Unfortunately, the size of `listResults` is returning 0 and I can't seem to figure out why. What's really funny is that when I change the query to

`Query.FilterPredicate listFilter = new Query.FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, listKey);`

`listResults` returns both items in the datastore.

Can anybody explain why this might be and how I might fix this?

Thanks!!!

EDIT:

`long listID = Long.parseLong(total_json.getString("listID"));`

is how I initialize listID

Comment: Can you please post how you initialize listID

Comment: I have posted how I initialized listID

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I created the entity in the database by writing

`list = new Entity("Lists", listKeyName);`

and I'm guessing that this made it only searchable on that key. I removed `listKeyName` and everything works fine now.